# Synchronizing 2 replicas with different primary key types

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

I am trying to synchronize 2 data stores using 2 custom providers. Each provider handles its own data store and each provider communicates using APIs which means I can't access the databases using built-in providers. The problem is replica A uses `long` as primary keys, but the Replica B uses `GUIDs` instead.
When I synchronize I get an exception saying:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The IsVariable setting of the specified ID instance is not consistent with the requested data type
at Microsoft.Synchronization.SyncId.GetGuidId()
```

I understand that the sync agent is trying to find the ItemMetdata using the long key but actually the ItemMetata exists but it was stored in GUIDs.
How can my application handle two replicas with 2 different primary keys?
Please note that I am not targeting SQL Databases.

Comment: can you enable Sync Fx tracing to see which stage it's actually failing?

Comment: Could you please tell me how can I trace? I read that I can register a listener, also I can use something called tracelog.exe. Which approach should I use? I'm sorry, but I am new to the SyncFx.